# Very long equation manipulation with arrows

Tags: equations, align, arrows

I was trying to fit this equation manipulation in a page as shown in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}

\usepackage{amsmath,cancel,witharrows}

\begin{document}

\noindent
some words
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
    P(t|t)&=E\left[\tilde{e}_x(t)\tilde{e}_x^T(t)\right]\\
    &=E\left[\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)^T\right] \Arrow[i]{$e_x$ is uncorrelated with $v(t)$\\collect $E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]$ and $E[v(t)v^T(t)]$}\\
    &=\big(I-K(t)C\big)E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)E[v(t)v^T(t)]K(t)\\
    &=\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)R_vK^T(t)\\
    &\begin{split}
        =P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        +K(t)CP(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)+K(t)R_vK^T(t)
    \end{split}
    \Arrow[i]{in the 4th and 5th terms,\\factor out $K(t)$}\\
    &\begin{split}
        =P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        +K(t)\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)
    \end{split}    
    \Arrow[i]{\eqref{eqn_kalman_filter_gain}}\\
    &\begin{split}=P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
    +\underbrace{P(t|t-1)C^T\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)^{-1}}_{=K(t)}\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)\end{split}\\
    &=P(t|t-1)\cancel{-P(t|t-1)C^T K^T(t)}-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\cancel{+P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)}\\
    &=P(t|t-1)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\Arrow[i]{factor out $P(t|t-1)$}\\
    P(t|t)&=\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)
\end{DispWithArrows*}
some other words

\end{document}
```

**Problem 1:**
The text displayed with the package `witharrows` and with the command `\Arrow[i]{...}` falls off the right edge of the sheet, while the equation doesn't start immediately at left but in the center-left of the sheet, so it doesn't exploit all the available space.

**Problem 2:**
I tried to use the `split` environment but it doesn't work very well because some equations don't start aligned with the others (I think it's because I don't use it properly) and because its efforts are useless due to problem 1.

If my description is not clear, the output of the MWE will be clearer:

[image: if my description is not clear, the output of the MWE will be clearer]

How can I solve these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the options `fleqn` and `mathindent=0pt`, i.e., start the equation with `\begin{DispWithArrows*}[fleqn,mathindent=0pt]`. This typesets the equation flush left .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Solution to problem 1:* Start the equation with `\begin{DispWithArrows*}[fleqn,mathindent=0pt]`. This typesets the equation flushed left. See the documentation of the package `witharrows` for an explanation.

*Solution to problem 2:* Precede the lines of the `split` environment with `&`. The first column of a `split` environment is right-aligned, the second one left aligned. Moreover, add `\quad` in lines that do not start with a relation symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}

\usepackage{amsmath,cancel,witharrows}

\begin{document}

\noindent
some words
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[fleqn,mathindent=0pt]
    P(t|t)&=E\left[\tilde{e}_x(t)\tilde{e}_x^T(t)\right]\\
    &=E\left[\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)^T\right] \Arrow[i]{$e_x$ is uncorrelated with $v(t)$\\collect $E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]$ and $E[v(t)v^T(t)]$}\\
    &=\big(I-K(t)C\big)E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)E[v(t)v^T(t)]K(t)\\
    &=\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)R_vK^T(t)\\
    &\begin{split}
        &=P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        &\quad+K(t)CP(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)+K(t)R_vK^T(t)
    \end{split}
    \Arrow[i]{in the 4th and 5th terms,\\factor out $K(t)$}\\
    &\begin{split}
        &=P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        &\quad+K(t)\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)
    \end{split}    
    \Arrow[i]{\eqref{eqn_kalman_filter_gain}}\\
    &\begin{split}
      &=P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
      &\quad+\underbrace{P(t|t-1)C^T\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)^{-1}}_{=K(t)}\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)\end{split}\\
    &=P(t|t-1)\cancel{-P(t|t-1)C^T K^T(t)}-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\cancel{+P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)}\\
    &=P(t|t-1)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\Arrow[i]{factor out $P(t|t-1)$}\\
    P(t|t)&=\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)
\end{DispWithArrows*}
some other words

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very neat solution, thank you!

Comment: ahahah amazing bio XD

Answer (score 4):

I propose this code, not perfect, but using the `fleqn` option and setting the value of `mathindent`.

I added some simplification of the code, and replaced the `|` for conditional probabilities with `\mid` which has a better spacing. Also, the pairs `\big( … \big)` with `\bigl(… \bigr)` for the same reason. Last, I replaced the `split` environment, which produced warnings messages, with `aligned`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=2.5cm, hmargin=2cm, heightrounded, bindingoffset=5mm, showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{amsmath, cancel, witharrows}

\begin{document}

\noindent
some words
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[fleqn, mathindent=1em, wrap-lines, show-nodes]
    P(t\mid t)&=E\left[\tilde{e}_x(t)\tilde{e}_x^T(t)\right]\\
    &=E\left[\bigl((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\bigr)\bigl((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\bigr)^T\right] \Arrow[i]{{$e_x$ is uncorrelated with $v(t)$\\ collect $E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]$ and $E[v(t)v^T(t)]$}}\\
    &=\bigl(I-K(t)C\bigr)E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]\bigl(I-K(t)C\bigr)^T+K(t)E[v(t)v^T(t)]K(t)\\
    &=\bigl(I-K(t)C\bigr)P(t\mid t-1)\bigl(I-K(t)C\bigr)^T+K(t)R_vK^T(t)\\
    &=\begin{aligned}[t]P(t\mid t-1) & -P(t\mid t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t\mid t-1)+{\,}\\
        & +K(t)CP(t\mid t-1)C^TK^T(t)+K(t)R_vK^T(t)
    \end{aligned}
    \Arrow[i]{in the 4th and 5th terms,\\factor out $K(t)$}\\
    &=\begin{aligned}[t]P(t\mid t-1) & -P(t\mid t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t\mid t-1)+{}\\
         & +K(t)\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)
    \end{aligned}
    \Arrow[i]{\eqref{eqn_kalman_filter_gain}}\\
    &=\begin{aligned}[t]P(t &\mid t-1) -P(t\mid t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t\mid t-1)+{}\\
     & +\underbrace{P(t\mid t-1)C^T\bigl(CP(t\mid t-1)C^T+R_v\bigr)^{-1}}_{=K(t)}\bigl(CP(t\mid t-1)C^T+R_v\bigr)K^T(t)
    \end{aligned}\\
    &=P(t\mid t-1)\cancel{-P(t\mid t-1)C^T K^T(t)}-K(t)CP(t\mid t-1)\cancel{+P(t\mid t-1)C^TK^T(t)}\\
    &=P(t\mid t-1)-K(t)CP(t\mid t-1)\Arrow[i]{factor out $P(t\mid t-1)$}\\
    P(t\mid t)&=\bigl(I-K(t)C\bigr)P(t\mid t-1)
\end{DispWithArrows*}
some other words

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard! I will immediately change the | character with \mid, it looks much better. Up to now I wrote all my conditional probabilities like that (^_^;). Same stuff for the parentheses. The aligned environment is neat, but is it possible to align the 2nd row to the first?

Comment: @Stefano: What  do you means exactly? All rows are aligned on the `=` sign. Could you explain more explicitly?

Comment: Yes, for example, look at the 6th line (right below the 5th equal sign). Is there a way to shift the line so that the plus sign is slightly to the right with respect to the equal sign?

Comment: I see. I had thought it looked fine to align the + sign with the – above (via the aligned environment. But instead, you may put the `&` in the line above  just before the `P` at the very beginning of the line above.

Comment: Oops, right, I didn't notice the other `&` sign

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is my analysis and suggestion for solution.

First I introduced some abbreviations via the `\def` macro to better see your structure. Already **with** adaptions described below it reads:

```
% --- formulas ----------------------------------------------------
\def\ZA{E\left[\tilde{e}_x(t)\tilde{e}_x^T(t)\right]}
\def\ZB{E\left[\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)^T\right]}
\def\ZCa{\big(I-K(t)C\big)E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)E[v(t)v^T(t)]K(t)}
\def\ZCb{\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)R_vK^T(t)}
\def\ZD{P(t|t-1)\cancel{-P(t|t-1)C^T K^T(t)}-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\cancel{+P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)}}
\def\AB{P(t|t-1)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\Arrow[i]{factor out $P(t|t-1)$}}
\def\AA{P(t|t)&=\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)}
% --- split groups -------------------------------------------------------
\def\SG{P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        +K(t)CP(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)+K(t)R_vK^T(t)}
\def\SH{P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        +K(t)\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)}
\def\SK{P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
    +\underbrace{P(t|t-1)C^T\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)^{-1}}_{=K(t)}\times \\
    \times\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)}
% --- arrow texts --------------------------------------------------------
\def\RA{$e_x$ is uncorrelated with\\ $v(t)$ collect\\ $E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]$ and\\ $E[v(t)v^T(t)]$}
\def\RB{in the 4th and 5th terms,\\factor out $K(t)$}
\def\RC{\eqref{eqn_kalman_filter_gain}}
% ------------------------------------
```

There is no particular naming. ZA..AB just are your formulas, SG, SH and SK are inside your split-environemnts, RA..RC are the arrow texts; all of them free from `&`, besides the `\underbrace`. With this your set of equations and hence your structure reads:

```
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[format = ll]
    P(t|t)  &=\ZA\\
            &=\ZB \Arrow[i]{\RA}\\% \RA is too long
            &=\ZCa\\
            &=\ZCb\\
            &\begin{split}% line #5, continuing with '+'
                  =\SG
            \end{split}
            \Arrow[i]{\RB}\\
            &\begin{split}
                  =\SH
             \end{split}    
            \Arrow[i]{\RC}\\% unreferenced eqn, yields ??
            &\begin{split}
                =\SK
            \end{split}\\
            &=\ZD\\
            &=\AB\\
    \AA
\end{DispWithArrows*}
```

A solution to the first arrow text can be obtained by just entering some '\' linebreaks manually, see `\def\RA.`

For problem 2 I suggest to split the line with `\times` as indicated in `\def\SK`, so that the remaining centered part is less of a distraction, hopefully.

As you can see I also entered the `[format = ll]` statement at the beginning of the `DispWithArrows*` environment, to make sure alignement as intended. So `%\noindent` becomes obsolete ... (done)

Some new problems remain, like the touching arrows #2 and #3.

**Result after 2 compile runs, at least**:

[image: result]

**Complete code, for your reference**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}

\usepackage{amsmath,cancel,witharrows}

% --- formulas ----------------------------------------------------
\def\ZA{E\left[\tilde{e}_x(t)\tilde{e}_x^T(t)\right]}
\def\ZB{E\left[\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)\big((I-K(t)C)e_x(t)-K(t)v(t)\big)^T\right]}
\def\ZCa{\big(I-K(t)C\big)E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)E[v(t)v^T(t)]K(t)}
\def\ZCb{\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)\big(I-K(t)C\big)^T+K(t)R_vK^T(t)}
\def\ZD{P(t|t-1)\cancel{-P(t|t-1)C^T K^T(t)}-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\cancel{+P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)}}
\def\AB{P(t|t-1)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)\Arrow[i]{factor out $P(t|t-1)$}}
\def\AA{P(t|t)&=\big(I-K(t)C\big)P(t|t-1)}
% --- split groups -------------------------------------------------------
\def\SG{P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        +K(t)CP(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)+K(t)R_vK^T(t)}
\def\SH{P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
        +K(t)\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)}
\def\SK{P(t|t-1)-P(t|t-1)C^TK^T(t)-K(t)CP(t|t-1)+\\
    +\underbrace{P(t|t-1)C^T\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)^{-1}}_{=K(t)}\times \\
    \times\big(CP(t|t-1)C^T+R_v\big)K^T(t)}
% --- arrow texts --------------------------------------------------------
\def\RA{$e_x$ is uncorrelated with\\ $v(t)$ collect\\ $E[e_x(t)e_x^T(t)]$ and\\ $E[v(t)v^T(t)]$}
\def\RB{in the 4th and 5th terms,\\factor out $K(t)$}
\def\RC{\eqref{eqn_kalman_filter_gain}}
% ------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%\noindent
some words
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[format = ll]
    P(t|t)  &=\ZA\\
            &=\ZB \Arrow[i]{\RA}\\% \RA is too long
            &=\ZCa\\
            &=\ZCb\\
            &\begin{split}% line #5, continuing with '+'
                  =\SG
            \end{split}
            \Arrow[i]{\RB}\\
            &\begin{split}
                  =\SH
             \end{split}    
            \Arrow[i]{\RC}\\% unreferenced eqn, yields ??
            &\begin{split}
                =\SK
            \end{split}\\
            &=\ZD\\
            &=\AB\\
    \AA
\end{DispWithArrows*}
some other words

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your modular way to write the equation is pretty cool, but it's not so feasible in my case. I don't understand the meaning of `[format = ll]` and "to make sure alignment as intended".

Comment: @Stefano, Fine :) // I refer to page 6 in https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/generic/witharrows/witharrows.pdf , where using this format is explained. It's intended to work as in tables, where you could align individual columns left (l), center (c) or right (r). Sometimes this is a source of error, so I tried to exert some control ;-) // Turned out that the line I split via `\times` was causing the "wrong alignment".

Comment: @Stefano, about the `\def` parts, the purpose was more for myself to better see the structure of your table-like part. It might have been that some `&` got misplaced hidden inside your formulas ... which wasn't :) // If it's useful in a regular document may depend. However, I myself strive for a clear coding here, because it's so easy to do sth wrong AND being unable to find it. // Perhaps it's a good idea to define such substitutes for smaller entities, which occure often, like `K(t)CP(t|t-1)`. Then you'd use the `\newcommand`-approach, not TeX as I did ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I was misled by the double l :)

As you said, the \def parts are very useful in this case but since I'm working on a document of 100+ pages with a lot of equations, it would take too long to create pieces of the equation and organize them in another .tex file. Moreover this a document containing the notes of an exam I have already given :))) There would be no need to change it, but I like to "tinker" with LaTeX. In the future, maybe for a project report or my master thesis, I will definitely use this kind of approach. Thank you again!